# Im can't get in player varibale server script. Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

Hello im make ore system and im have 2 scripts. In first im make power in player use int varibale. In secend im use this power, but always get wrongs.

FIRST SCRIPT: Server, in ServerScriptService

```
local players = game.Players

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local power = Instance.new("IntValue", player)
    power.Name = "power"
    power.Value = 50
end)
```

SECEND: server, in object

```
local prox = script.Parent
local ore = prox.Parent.Parent.Ore
local power = game.Players.LocalPlayer or game:GetService("Players").LocalScript or game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Wait()
wait(0.01)
prox.ObjectText = ore.Value
prox.ActionText = ore.Price.Value.."$"
print(m.power)
```

im try all so many metod add varibale localplayer, and some use module

Comment: im try so many*

Comment: Using `Instance.new()` with the second argument can be bad for performance, as shown in [this post](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/psa-dont-use-instancenew-with-parent-argument/30296).
I would recommend replacing the first script with this, it won't solve the problem but it could prevent performance issues in the future.
```local players = game.Players

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local power = Instance.new("IntValue")
    power.Name = "power"
    power.Value = 50
    power.Parent = player
end)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is pretty unclear. What is `m`? How do you get "wrong"? What's wrong? Do you get an error, a warning or does it just "not work"? If you be more specific, especially about what the wrong thing is, we will be able to give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Roblox has two types of scripts, Server Sided and Client Sided.

**Server Sided**
Server Sided scripts are on the **server** side of your game and are able to access all instances. However, this has some downsides. This means there is no "Local Player".

**Client Sided**
The client-side has scripts that are specifically tuned for that Player. An example of this is UI. UI is placed into StarterGui and duplicated once the game is started into each Player's PlayerUI. The client side is Player Side. However, this means we can't edit instances from the Client side that are usually on the server side. If you attempt to change something that is usually on the server side, the instance will be changed but only for the player. It's pretty complicated.

Long story short, you cannot call for LocalPlayer in a server-sided script as server-sided is not defined for a specific player but for the entire game.

This is a long answer and I apologize if It's complicated, but I wanted to give a bit more information to help you and others understand the difference.